# How can I get Grafana Server Admin Role in Grafana 7.5

Tags: grafana

I want to view Admin stats but it requires Grafana Server Admin role permission which is different from Organization Role. Can someone tell me how to get this permission?

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v7.5/permissions/#grafana-server-admin-role https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v7.5/manage-users/server-admin/server-admin-manage-users/#permissions

Comment: currently i have orgs admin role. is there any way to know which user has these privileges or can we set this flag programmatically?

Comment: I don't have that old Grafana at hand to test it, but if no major changes were maid (and think so), org admin cannot even see privileges server-wide privileges. The only ones who can appoint other server admins are server admins: it is done on "Server admin" page.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was just wandering can there be a case where we dont have no one with “Server Admin” permission? or someone must have it?

Comment: AFAIK, there must be at least one account with "Server admin" role. If you lost credentials, I believe it is possible to reset them. [This](https://community.grafana.com/t/admin-password-reset/19455) might help.